# PHP Half-Complete File Prevention

Tags: php

In PHP, I will be using:

```
file_put_contents();
```

To write to a file. The issue is in my head, what if there is a GET request for the file while it's being written by another PHP thread? Will the file be sent half-written? Also, how can I prevent the file from being server half-written?

Comment: it will be locked until fully written, so it will never be half sent

Comment: While the server is performing a function on a file, either no one else can access that file or the server just sends a cached version.

Comment: I believe there is no problem. Usually only one operation at a time can be done to a file or a database. They lock it when modifying it and unlock it when it is done, and ready for the next.

Comment: I don't think that there is ever a cached version going from server to user, as servers do not cache that kind of stuff. Operations on files are almost always lightning fast.

Comment: Did this used to be different? I was reading some other articles saying it posed a risk of the file being halfwritten when another file accesses it. Does it protect the file while writing from all other software (such as Apache) or just PHP itself?

Comment: sounds unlikely, can you point to the article you read? i would expect what ever user is writing the file has exclusive access until it finishes

Comment: Scroll down to the 6 years ago comment on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php I am guessing that perhaps things have changed since 6 years, but the user said one person can read while another's writing.

Comment: ok, so add the flag `LOCK_EX`

Comment: If you are reading value into memory and then incrementing, you risk updates to the file getting out of order so that older data updates the file after newer data.  That's why with a db you do like `update accounts SET dollarsInAccount = dollarsInAccount + 10 where accountId = X` rather than read the value in table, update in PHP, then do `update accounts SET dollarsInAccount = 25 where accountId = X` which is basically what you have to do with a text file. So you can end up losing money from the account when transactions get out of order, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

php file access is just plain system file access, mutexes are not built in.  Especially since the reader would be a separate process from the writer.  I've seen php interleave two log messages to an append-only logfile (one message was very large), so not only are writes not atomic, not even appends are.

If this is a new file,
you can save it to a hidden name or hidden folder that will not be visible to downloads, and rename() the file when done.